# Counting specific values in rows in CSV

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a csv file:

```
A   D1      B    D2     C         D3    E
1   action  0.5  action 0.35    null    a
2   0       0.75    0   0.45    action  b
3   action  1    action 0.85    action  c
```

I want to count the number of 'action' keyword in each row and make a new column giving the output. So the output file would be something like this.

```
A   D1        B   D2    C         D3    E   TotalAction
1   action  0.5  action 0.35    null    a   2
2   0       0.75    0   0.45    action  b   1
3   action  1    action 0.85    action  c   3
```

What is the best way to go forward using Pandas? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [select_dtypes](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) (for selecting only *string* columns) in conjunction with `.sum(axis=1)`:

```
In [95]: df['TotalAction'] = (df.select_dtypes(include=[object]) == 'action').sum(axis=1)

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
   A      D1     B      D2     C      D3  E  TotalAction
0  1  action  0.50  action  0.35    null  a            2
1  2       0  0.75       0  0.45  action  b            1
2  3  action  1.00  action  0.85  action  c            3
```

**Timing** against 30K rows DF:

```
In [3]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [6]: df.shape
Out[6]: (30000, 7)

In [4]: %timeit df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('action').sum(), axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 7.89 s per loop

In [5]: %timeit (df.select_dtypes(include=[object]) == 'action').sum(axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.08 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit df.isin(['action']).sum(axis=1)
10 loops, best of 3: 22.8 ms per loop
```

**Conclusion:** `apply(...)` is 1114 times slower compared to `select_dtypes()` method

**Explanation:**

```
In [92]: df.select_dtypes(include=[object])
Out[92]:
       D1      D2      D3  E
0  action  action    null  a
1       0       0  action  b
2  action  action  action  c

In [93]: df.select_dtypes(include=[object]) == 'action'
Out[93]:
      D1     D2     D3      E
0   True   True  False  False
1  False  False   True  False
2   True   True   True  False

In [94]: (df.select_dtypes(include=[object]) == 'action').sum(axis=1)
Out[94]:
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: + for speed, but I think `isin` is more readable and its perfomance close to your method.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov, i would combine both our solutions into: `df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).isin(['action', 'action2']).sum(axis=1)` - so it will be fast and flexible ;)

Comment: @MaxU, Anton Protopopov, Both solutions work excellent. I wonder why we need databases when we have Pandas. This is really cool stuff. I tried it on my file for some 12000 rows and 1000 columns. df.select_dtypes compiled around 6 seconds faster.

Comment: @DigantaBharali, `I wonder why we need databases when we have Pandas` - it's true unless you reach your memory limit. :) But, hey, there is an Apache Spark SQL with dataframes support...

Comment: @MaxU, will check that out. Ok here is a slight problem I found while doing the test run. In certain rows, where there are values like 'Attactions' with the word 'action' in it, it is counting those values as well

Comment: @DigantaBharali, don't use `.str.contains()` - try to use `df.select_dtypes(include=[object]).isin(['action', 'action2']).sum(axis=1)` or the one from my answer if you are checking for a single value

Comment: @MaxU,  Anton Protopopov. Just out of curiosity, I have say columns `D_1_col, D_2_col, D_3_col,......D_44_col`. Now for each row i want to get the count of the above columns having a value. So that i dont have to count by a particular keyword. For example, in row 1 if there are values just under column D_3_col and D_6_col, the count would be 2.

Comment: @DigantaBharali, i don't understand what do you mean saying: `to get the count of the above columns having a value`

Comment: @MaxU, its like i don,t want the count by a specific keyword. Say 3 of those columns(say D_1_col, D_5_col and D_10_col) have some value under them for the 1st row and other columns have null. So, the count for the first row under 'TotalAction' would be 3

Comment: but in this case you are counting ALL not-null values - i thought your task was bit different...

Comment: @MaxU, it got changed. The 'action' thing was a bit specific. This approach is more generic. Because there were files where i needed to take into account other keywords as well. And i have to search the entire file for that particular keyword for which it is increasing the count if i go by the first approach!

Comment: Give it a try! If you will need further assistance please open a new question and describe your new approach, because it's difficult to understand not being able to see the whole picture or the things that got changed. ;)

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`apply`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwjRje2D9MrNAhWDXSwKHZF0DGIQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.apply.html&usg=AFQjCNGwp68FvdZdfl9wKRRIK7cWW5kV3g&sig2=xOYaNZLH7-iN_pTquBr8UQ&bvm=bv.125596728,d.bGg) across the rows with [`str.contains`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjt8dL688rNAhVHhiwKHX5iD6AQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.Series.str.contains.html&usg=AFQjCNE7tXqErGZZYEuST7VOKjSXqGPzwQ&sig2=5rhwBRhTnMTZMNcT2PMADQ&bvm=bv.125596728,d.bGg) for that keyword:

```
In [21]: df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('action').sum(), axis=1)
Out[21]:
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64

df['TotalAction'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('action').sum(), axis=1)

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   A      D1     B      D2     C      D3  E  TotalAction
0  1  action  0.50  action  0.35    null  a            2
1  2       0  0.75       0  0.45  action  b            1
2  3  action  1.00  action  0.85  action  c            3
```

**EDIT**

Although you could do it easier and faster with [`isin`](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiW98iK9srNAhVGESwKHQUwCKcQFggbMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpandas.pydata.org%2Fpandas-docs%2Fstable%2Fgenerated%2Fpandas.DataFrame.isin.html&usg=AFQjCNHvPOKgLEzZokkqyKlKmw2-DPotOw&sig2=3Sqq-c8CC9qiipOZbdwT1Q&bvm=bv.125596728,d.bGg) and then sum across the rows:

```
In [45]: df.isin(['action']).sum(axis=1)
Out[45]:
0    2
1    1
2    3
dtype: int64
```

*Note*: You need to wrap your string keyword into `list`.

Comment: the only problem with `str.contains` is that it counts all strings that have the value `action` in it. In my case it counts the words `Attractions` for example. The other solutions work fine